# Codeigniter force download a pdf file doesn't do anything

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, pdf, download

this is my first time doing a codeigniter downloading a pdf file from a recently uploaded file. I've searched some codes and I came up with this:

```
if($get_file->file_type == 'pdf') {
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $pth = file_get_contents(base_url()."/assets/img/requirements_pdf/1602553016_Johns_Resume_(1).pdf");                    
    $nme = "1602553016_Johns_Resume_(1).pdf";
    force_download($nme, $pth);
}
```

Now when I tried this code, there was no error when I check the network and it returns status code 200 but give me with a response of a long random characters,numbers and symbols. Any problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download an actual file from your server the first argument needs to be the path, also this way you can't rename it. `force_download($pth, null);`

If you want to also rename it than you could read the file into a var with `file_get_contents($pth)` and go the original way. Just remember that large files might cause some out of memory issues.

Also what you get on output that wierd chars is your file. It might be some browser addons or settings that blocking download or mimes are not set right